# Possible to restrict a PowerPoint template?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, templates

I have a need to achieve the following:

A PowerPoint template where the user can only use certain styles (fonts, size, colors, etc).

Is it possible to have this restriction in PowerPoint (2007).  Through code?

all thoughts appreciated.

Comment: You can write VBA code for all office applications.

Answer (score 3):

As kishore suggested you can write VBA to probably limit available choices, but the users could always disable the macros and have free reign. If you're in an corporate setting just providing a list of sane default color themes, fonts, and font sizes while removing other color themes and having a manager send out memos explaining only to use the approved corporate theme/fonts and colors should suffice.